# Storing Excel chart line properties in Access database

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am storing the details of an EXCEL plot in an ACCESS database using VBA.  I can set the line width of a series in an EXCEL chart window from 0 to >10 pt using the `format data series` form.  I store the weight of series by reading the `Series.Format.Line.Weight` property of each line.  However, this seems only to store the EXCEL enumerated values `xlThin`, `xlThick` rather than the defined thickness of the line in points.  Is it possible to store the actual thicknesses rather than the enumerated values?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce that: If I check `Series.Format.Line.Weight`, I get exactly the line width I specified.

Comment: This is close! There must be an enumeration of the thickness somewhere, perhaps called the Line Weight.   https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/office/vba/api/excel.xllinestyle

Comment: Closer but still not there.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlborderweight

Comment: @FunThomas - thanks for checking.  The issue is me not Excel - I defined the variable to represent the line thickness as `long` - the issue is resolved when I change to `double`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was me not EXCEL and is to do with variable typing.  Two problems: (a) the variable used to store line thickness was defined as `long` rather than `double` in the VBA code (b) the ACCESS field where the thickness was stored was defined as `long` rather than `double`.  Have corrected both issues and everything seems to work - thanks to all who looked into this